# Azure Dedicated Cache Across Multiple Cloud Services

Tags: azure, azure-caching

I have two cloud services one service also contain dedicated cache worker role from other cloud service how can I put data in dedicated cache on other cloud service?

Answer (score 2):

Role based caching is limited to a single cloud service.

You will need to go through the VIP (i.e. expose a public facing web method) or create a  VNET (that combines the two services)